# ADAL AcquireTokenByRefreshTokenAsync not updating TokenCache

Tags: c#, adal

We are using ADAL V2.29.0 to try an accomplish a rolling AccessToken.  IE the AccessToken expires in 4 days but the RefreshToken expires in 7 days.  Everytime you log in your RefreshToken gets a new AccessToken (thus expiring 4 days from your last login)

We are using AcquireTokenByRefreshTokenAsycn() and we are getting back a new updated AccessToken.  However, The TokenCache is not being updated and it is not writing the new token to our tokenPath.

How can we set the TokenCache dictionaryItem to be the result from AquireTokenByRefreshTokenAsync?

```
AuthenticationContext ac = new AuthenticationContext( strAuthority, false, tokenFileCache );

//Authenticate using a refresh token and get new Access Token   
var refreshTokenString = File.ReadAllText( Path.Combine( appDataPath, refreshToken ) );
ar = await ac.AcquireTokenByRefreshTokenAsync( refreshTokenString, strClientIdentifier );
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the AquireTokenByRefreshToken call in ADAL is designed not to access the TokenCache.  The TokenCache under the hood is a ConcurrentDictionary which is a private member of the TokenCache and is inaccessible from outside ADAL framework.   Good luck to everyone trying to do this. I would think it would be more common than what I have found searching